# Polars string column to pl.datetime in Polars: conversion issue

Tags: python-datetime, python-polars

working with a csv file with the following schema

> 'Ticket ID': polars.datatypes.Int64,
> ..
> 'Created time': polars.datatypes.Utf8,
> 'Due by Time': polars.datatypes.Utf8,
> ..

Converting to Datetime:

```
df = (
      df.lazy()
          .select(list_cols)
          .with_columns([
              pl.col(convert_to_date).str.strptime(pl.Date, fmt='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M',strict=False).alias("Create_date") #.cast(pl.Datetime) 
              ])
              )
```

Here is the output. 'Created time' is the original str and 'Create_date' is the conversion:

| Created time | Create_date |
| --- | --- |
| str | date |
| 04-01-2021 10:26 | 2021-01-04 |
| 04-01-2021 10:26 | 2021-01-04 |
| 04-01-2021 10:26 | 2021-01-04 |
| 04-01-2021 11:48 | 2021-01-05 |
| ... | ... |
| 22-09-2022 22:44 | null |
| 22-09-2022 22:44 | null |
| 22-09-2022 22:44 | null |
| 22-09-2022 22:47 | null |

Getting a bunch of nulls and some of the date conversions seems to be incorrect (see 4th row in the output above). Also, how may I keep the time values?

Sure I am doing something wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pyarrow as pa
import pandas as pd

convert_to_date = ['Created time','Due by Time','Resolved time','Closed time','Last update time','Initial response time']

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DOakville/PolarsDate/main/3000265945_tickets-Dates.csv'

df = (
      pl.read_csv(url,parse_dates=True)
      ) 

df = df.with_column(
        pl.col(convert_to_date).str.strptime(pl.Date, fmt='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M',strict=False).alias("Create_date") #.cast(pl.Datetime) 
              )
```

Comment: Can you post a self-contained example with a few lines of data? Would be useful to help understand exactly what is happening and suggest a fix/workaround. (I can see the values in the table, but in case there is a difference in your file it would be good to see the original values as well).

Comment: Hi Alexander, it was too long for the comment box, so I have posted the code that read from a git file above in the body text. Hopefully it works and is what you requested. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh... I think I see what is happening - your `with_columns` expression is successfully converting all of the columns given in the "convert_to_date" list, *but* assigning the result of each conversion to the same name: "Create date".

So, the values you finally get are coming from the *last* column to be converted ("Initial response time"), which does have nulls where you see them.

If you want each column to be associated with a separate date-converted entry, you can use the `suffix` expression to ensure that each conversion is mapped to its own distinct output column (based on the original name).

For example:

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.col(convert_to_date).str.strptime(
        datatype = pl.Date,
        fmt = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M',
    ).suffix(" date")  # << adds " date" to the existing column name  
)
```

Or, if you prefer to overwrite the existing columns with the converted ones, you could keep the existing column names:

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.col(convert_to_date).str.strptime(
        datatype = pl.Date,
        fmt = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'
    ).keep_name()  # << keeps original name (effectively overwriting it)
)
```

Finally, if you actually want datetimes (not dates), just change the value of the `datatype` param in the strptime expression to `pl.Datetime`.